# Retrieve multiple selected option flyout windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a button in bottom bar of windows 8 app. And on clicking that button, I have a flyout showing multiple options. I have added a tag "multiple" in the html of Flyout. And it is allowing me too select multiple options. But I am able to retrieve only last selected value using flyoutid.value command. Can someone please help me to retrieve multiple options selected for flyout.

Thanks.

Comment: pl share html for the flyout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [selectElement.options](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp) and [option.selected](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_option.asp) dom property.

```
// assumes appbar id for the appbar
flyout.winControl.show(appbar);
var selectElement = flyout.querySelector('select');
selectElement.onchange = function (event)
{
    var target = event.currentTarget;
    for (var i = 0; i < target.options.length; i++)
    {
        var option = target.options[i];
        if (option.selected)
            console.info('option ' + option.value + ' is selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like this, in my onchange function of flyout
var flyout = document.getElementById("flyoutID").winControl;

var value = flyout.options.length;
But this is giving me error, I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: remove `winControl` from first statement. `var flyout = document.getElementById("flyoutID");`